# How to change the input language of an MS-DOS program

Tags: keyboard, dos

I have this MS-DOS program that I want to run on a different computer but even though the language is set to Turkish, when I run this particular software it accepts the keys as if they were coming from an English keyboard. The regular command prompt accepts the keys just fine but just this one program will not allow Turkish characters. I used to be able to run this on another computer just fine but now it's giving me problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is set in the KEYBRD2.SYS and COUNTRY.SYS files. More information is here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/117850